# TypeError in Rhino: migration from Java 6 to Java 7

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

My project perfectly works on Java 6 (different updates and OS). It uses Rhino as script engine. Now we need to migrate to Java 7 and I found one issue that prevent us to do it.
We have code like this:

```
Context.enter();
try {
    ScriptEngine js = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js");
    final ScriptContext context = new SimpleScriptContext();
    context.setAttribute("console", new Object() {
        public void log(String out) {
            logger.info(out);
        }
    }, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
    js.setContext(context);
    js.eval("console.log('test')");
} catch (ScriptException e) {
    logger.error(e);
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    Context.exit();
}
```

It works good in Java 6 but Java 7 throws exception

```
javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function log in object JSDebugTest$1@4631f1f8. (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1
at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:224)
at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:240)
at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
at JSDebugTest.testJS1(JSDebugTest.java:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at  com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:76)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function log in object JSDebugTest$1@4631f1f8. (<Unknown source>#1)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3771)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3749)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3777)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3796)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3867)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2343)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2310)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.gen._Unknown_source__2._c_script_0(<Unknown source>:1)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.gen._Unknown_source__2.call(<Unknown source>)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:433)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3161)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.gen._Unknown_source__2.call(<Unknown source>)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.gen._Unknown_source__2.exec(<Unknown source>)
at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Context.evaluateReader(Context.java:1159)
at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:214)
... 30 more
```

Problem disappear if I extract anonymous Object to inner class. Any idea how to fix it without `ScriptableObject.get` (there are too many places where we create such object and some third party code we use, uses same approach)?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error, and after your comment "Problem disappear if I extract anonymous Object to inner class." I found that generated inner class will have default access modifier (sometimes called 'package' access modifier). Apparently, scripting API in JDK7 doesn't handle these definitions!

I use put a "static public" definition instead.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem.  I was passing in a private inner class and it was failing.  I changed it from a private inner object to a public class and it worked just fine after the Java 7 upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I also got TypeError when migrating from Java 6 to 7: my JavaScript was calling a method on a Java class which had default (package-private) visibility. Had to make the class public for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. In my case it was not an inner class, but the top level class had a default (package level) protection. Switching to `public` fixed my issues ... shame it took me a couple hours to figure it out.