# Why does Rhino Javascript engine complain a function does not exist?

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

Please forgive me, as I am a Java man dabbling in Javascript business :)

I wanted to be able to define a set of integration test cases to be easy to script against a Java application. I thought Javascript would be a perfect language to script against. To that end, I am using the Rhino engine that comes with JDK 7, via Java's Scripting API. The scripts would have access to Java classes already defined in the application, and could be reused to define use case scenarios for integration testing.

In the Java application, I have binded the javascript engine itself to the script as jsengine, so that I can load javascript files ([Including a JavaScript file during Rhino eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357334/including-a-javascript-file-during-rhino-eval)).

I have two Javascript files, as defined below:

Function.js:

```
function send(msg) {
    send.sendMessage(msg);
}
```

TestCase.js

```
jsengine.eval(new java.io.FileReader("Function.js");

sendMsg("Test Message");
```

I also have the following object defined and binded to the script as "javaobj":

```
public class TestConnection {

    ...

    public void send(String message) {
        // Code to send the string message via JMS
    }

}
```

However, the Rhino engine complains with the following Exception. It seems to not like calling the javaobj's send method, for some reason.

```
javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function send in object 
function sendMsg(msg) {...}. (TestCase.js#3) in TestCase.js at line number 3
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:224)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:212)
    at com.foo.test.scenario.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:56)
    at com.foo.test.TestSuite.start(TestSuite.java:88)
    at com.foo.test.TestSuite.main(TestSuite.java:41)
Caused by: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function send in object 
function sendMsg(msg) {...}. (TestCase.js#3) in TestCase.js at line number 3
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3773)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3751)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3779)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3798)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3869)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2345)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2312)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1524)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:854)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:164)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:429)
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.superDoTopCall(RhinoScriptEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.doTopCall(RhinoScriptEngine.java:109)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3163)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:175)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Context.evaluateReader(Context.java:1159)
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:214)
    ... 4 more
```

Has anyone ever encountered this type of issue with Rhino?

P.S. This question seems related, but no answer given as well ([TypeError in Rhino: migration from Java 6 to Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634585/typeerror-in-rhino-migration-from-java-6-to-java-7))

Comment: Probably need a bit more code here. The code here looks correct, at least to me, but perhaps there's an issue with the code you haven't shown.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found my own answer. There was a name conflict between the Javascript function and the name of the binded Java object. Both having the same name, the engine tries to call a non-existent method on a Function object!

Silly me... :P

Comment: I still do not know how you resolved it. I have written an Ant scriptdef that uses a mix of Java and Javascript code. I am trying to call trim() on my variable and getting a similar error. How do I go about telling mozilla engine to use Java version, or even the Javascript version, as both should do the work?